# How do I include HTML from an attribute as a token in a directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to inject HTML as an attribute into a template and have it display within the directive that passed the attribute.

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div>
      <my-test mymessage='<b>Booya!</b>'></my-test>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

My Javascript

```
app = angular.module('app', [])
.directive("myTest", function(){
    return {
        scope: {
          mymessage: '='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<p>Guess what...{{mymessage}}...you know it!</p>'
    };
  });
```

Here is the code in Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZJSkf1Ye4ccKURTJU8KD?p=preview

Note how it shows the literal for the binding.

I'm sure there are several problems here:

1. I am probably not properly binding the attribute within the directive scope
2. Once I have problem #1 solved I am pretty sure the HTML will be escaped.

What changes do I need to make in order to get the directive to render properly?

Comment: I'd use a directive controller and set your scope there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are binding HTML without Angular code (expressions and directives), then you need to use [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml):

```
scope: {
  mymessage: "@" // no need for two-way binding
},
template: '<p>Guess what...<span ng-bind-html="mymessage"></span>...you know it!</p>'
```

This, on its own, would not work since it is unsafe. You have two options then:

1) include `ngSanitize` dependecy to your app:

```
angular.module("app", ["ngSanitize"])
```

This will automatically apply HTML sanitation - [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/NEBUVIvso10ms4WXfOmc?p=preview)

or, 2) use `$sce` service and call `$sce.trustAsHtml` on the variable holding the HTML content. This would not work, however with one-way string binding `"@"`.

Comment: Your demo has the exact visual results I want. I'm wondering if #2 gets me closer to how I'd prefer to format the template. Can you tell me a bit more about your #2 option.

Comment: @JosephU. There is a difference between the two. `ngSanitize` sanitizes the output, whereas `trustAsHtml` just fully trusts that there is nothing evil in the injected HTML - so, they are not equivalent. You'd still need `ng-bind-html`, so I'm not sure what you mean by "closer to how you'd format the template".

Comment: My hope is that I could somehow keep {{mymessage}} in the template and sanitize the value without introducing a new tag (i.e. Span).

Comment: I played around with your demo code and switched the SPAN tag to something completely random and it still displays perfectly. Thank you to all who took the time to answer you guys are a god send.

Comment: @JosephU., I'm not familiar with any trivial way. `{{ }}` is a shorthand for `ng-bind`, which treats the input as text.